# Is there a way to get Solr to generate Facet counts on just the Result set of docs instead of across all documents

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I am using the Solr Admin UI to build this query:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/gencat.imagemetadata/select?q=id:"TH-1961-46483-10968-9"&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=externalid`

It returns:

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "TH-1961-46483-10968-9",
        "externalid": "100700000_00024"
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {},
    "facet_fields": {
      "externalid": [
        "100700000_00024",
        1,
        "005471837_00001",
        0,
        "005471837_00002",
        0,
        "005471837_00003",
        0,
        "005471837_00099",
        0,
        ....
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My assumption was it was only going to return facet counts for the one document it found (since I’m specifying the id I want).   Instead, it returns a `facet_counts` structure with every `externalid` value indexed by Solr (granted…all but one entry is 0.  The `externalid` count for the document matching the query is 1 as it aught to be).  But I only want Solr facet counts for the documents in the search results.  Not everything.  It slows down the query significantly.

Yes, I can set `facet.mincount = 1` to cause it to only return facet counts that actually have counts, but under the covers it still looks like it is looking at all of the documents…not just the queried result set.  It is currently taking 2 minutes to execute the query above on our 2+ Billion items.

When I turn `tracing on;` in cqlsh I can see that it is processing across all 2+ Billion items.  If it were to only count over the result set this query would be much, much faster.

`externalid` is defined like this in the schema file:

```
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="externalid" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
```

What am I misunderstanding?
It is slowing down my query by having to go out and find all of the externalid’s just to say they have a count of 0.

Is there a way to tell Solr faceting to only look at the docs found from the query?

I am on Solr 6 under DSE 6.0

Comment: Faceting is done after the query is done (as Mats writes "iterating over documents that match the query"), so your assumption is correct. Could it be that your query itself is taking very long and that the poor performance has nothing to do with faceting?

Answer (score 0):

You can give [the facet method](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.methodParameter) through the `facet.method` parameter. `fc` is the default, and this is the behavior you're looking for - are you sure that DSE are actually using `fc` as the method by default? (since the definition for `fc` is that it should only iterate over documents matching the query):

> **fc**
>
> Calculates facet counts by *iterating over documents* that match the query and summing the terms that appear in each document.
>
> This is currently implemented using an UnInvertedField cache if the field either is multi-valued or is tokenized (according to FieldType.isTokened()). Each document is looked up in the cache to see what terms/values it contains, and a tally is incremented for each value.
>
> This method is *excellent for situations where the number of indexed values for the field is high, but the number of values per document is low*. For multi-valued fields, a hybrid approach is used that uses term filters from the filterCache for terms that match many documents. The letters fc stand for field cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to change anything.  I tried:

`GET /solr/gencat.imagemetadata/select?q=id:"TH-1961-46483-10968-9"&amp;wt=json&amp;indent=true&amp;facet=true&amp;facet.field=externalid&amp;facet.method=fc`

And it still appears to iterate over all documents as it still return zero counts for values that are on documents outside of what the query results returns.

facet.method=enum didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried the JSON facet API? It offers more methods than the regular faceting API as well.

Comment: And - what's the speed the second time the query is issued? And does changing mincount do anything? (if mincount is 0, it would be necessary to fetch all terms - and not just those in the document)

Comment: Executing a second time is still slow.  No noticeable speed up.  

Changing the `facet.mincount=1` sure enough only returns the one entry in the facet_counts.  But it is still as slow.  I still think that under the covers it is trying to determine all of the buckets/facets available for externalid.

Comment: Did you try using the JSON Facet API? And possibly the `domain / filter` key as well?

Comment: By the way...it appears facet.method=fc is the default.  The description above (and in the docs) does appear to be just as I would expect.

Comment: Using the JSON Facet API is still slow.  I tried `/solr/gencat.imagemetadata/select?q=id:"TH-1961-46483-10968-9"&amp;wt=json&amp;indent=true&amp;rows=0&amp;json.facet={ externalid_facets : { field: externalid} }` and it still takes 2 minutes; even though it only returns 1 facet without having to specify mincount=1.

Comment: You could try specifying `facet.distrib.mco=true` together with `facet.mincount=1` as per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8988